# Why in the nuclide chart the $Q_{\alpha}$-value (the energy released in an alpha decay) is listed even for stable nuclides?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation

When I was studying some graphs I started comparing data with the nuclide chart of https://nds.iaea.org, and I noticed that even for nuclides that aren't typically alpha emitters, even for stable nuclides, is listed the energy released in an alpha decay ($Q_{\alpha}$). How is this possible, or better why is important to display such information for stable nuclides ?

Comment: Because you can determine the energy of a nucleus with two fewer protons and neutrons in it...

Comment: That's for sure, but what is the sense in doing it for stable nuclides ? I can in fact even evaluate the energy of a nuclide with 3 or 4 fewer neutrons or protons, say, but there is no sense in doing it

Comment: There are plenty of externally-driven nuclear reactions that have the net result being an alpha particle leaving the (compound) nucleus. It isn't just spontaneous decay that you worry about in nuclear physics.

Comment: Can you mention one of these particular reactions that results in an emission of a alpha particle for a stable nuclide ?

Comment: Sure: 28Si(n,a)25Mg - the 29Si compound nucleus is stable. Many more like that in the ENDF database.